# Arrange the following questions in the order of basicity? Also Tell why?

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]

The main confusion is between the compound (a) and compound (b) because in compound (c) we get aromatic ring(above) upon cleavage of double bond on N so it must be best whereas in compound (d) we get an anti aromatic ring (above ) so it must be least but what about coumpound (a) and (b).

Comment: A positively charged species is unlikEly to attract H+

Comment: The stability of the conjugate acid in case of a) is lesser than that of b), because of the increased electron withdrawing effects of N atom.

Comment: After the cleavage of the double bond between N and Upper ring , the positive charge of the nitrogen will no longer be there so it will the surely attract H+   @Waylander